# Download file php in the server

Tags: php, download

in the localhost i get everything perfect but when i upload it to the server i get this error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(
hier is my code

```
    <?php

function download($file){
    $dir = './download/';
    $path = $dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($path)){
        die('Error');
    }else{
        header('Content-Description : File Transfer');
        header('Content-Disposition : attachment; filename='.basename($path));
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        ob_start();
        flush();
        readfile($path);
        exit;
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
    if (!empty($_GET['download'])) {
        $file = $_GET['download'];
        download($file);
    }
}
 ?>

<a class="download-template" href="example.php?download=Modern.rar">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the whitespace before the `<?php`

Like so

```
<?php

function download($file){
    $dir = './download/';
    $path = $dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($path)){
        die('Error');
    }else{
        header('Content-Description : File Transfer');
        header('Content-Disposition : attachment; filename='.basename($path));
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        ob_start();
        flush();
        readfile($path);
        exit;
    }
}
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
    if (!empty($_GET['download'])) {
        $file = $_GET['download'];
        download($file);
    }
}
 ?>

<a class="download-template" href="example.php?download=Modern.rar">Download</a>
```

The error is telling you that you're outputting content before it should do.

If you output content then the page headers have already been sent, so your call to `header()` will fail because the headers have already gone. And headers are always sent first.

By removing the whitespace there is no content to send, so the headers are not sent, so the call to `header` will then work and not error.

Comment: i took all the whitespace but stil the same problems

Comment: Hmm, just read the comment, that this was not the issue. But I came back here to ask you @JakeN, why this would have possibly with the mistake worked on the development server, but not on a *server*?

Comment: They could have completely difference configurations. Who knows TBH.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file encoding to "without BOM" (e.g. using notepad++) or remove the BOM before

Comment: i think we have another problem

Comment: i change the code in localhost stil working good but in th server not Notis: i change the file permission to 755

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use the following code for download any type of file extensions(including .php,.html):
    <?php 
    $filename = $test_data['test_name'];
    $contenttype = "application/octet-stream";
    header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
    readfile(ADMIN_ROOT.'modules/tests/test_pdfs/'.$filename);
    exit();
    ?>

Or you can check in this link working example:
http://websamplenow.com/29/file_download
```